# lua string match with variable string and variable pattern

Tags: string, lua, pattern-matching, string-matching

I have a long variable string stored in a table index like so:

```
my_table[4] = MYHOST1.fully.qualfied.com
```

I have a list of hostnames I read from a file which come back as a string.  I'm iterating through this with a for loop.

```
MYHOST1 MYHOST2 MYHOST3
```

---

For some reason:

```
print (string.match(match_string, machine))
```

doesn't match, even though, "match_string" holds the correct value from my table and "machine" holds the correct name which I iterating over.  Is there something special I need to do with a variable string here?

### Here is the whole function with a lot of debug in it right now. I am not sure if I am formatting this write for the forum. . . .my copy and paste was very messy.

```
function read_giant_file(file_name)
local header_true = 0
local max_fields = 1
local machine_count = table.maxn(machine_names)
local machine_list = table.concat(machine_names,' ')
--print (machine_count)
--print (machine_list)
for line in io.lines(file_name) do                                                      
    for machine in machine_list:gmatch"%g-[%s]" do                                  
            print ("machine: "..machine)                                            

            for field in line:gmatch("(.-)\t") do                                   
                    table.insert(field_table, field_index, field)                   
                    print ("field_index: "..field_index.. "field: "..field)      
                    field_index = field_index + 1                                   

            end    

            if header_true == 0 then                                                
                    for key, value in pairs(field_table) do                         
                            print ("key: "..key," ".."header: "..value)             
                    end                                                             
                    header_true = 1                                                 
                    max_fields = table.maxn(field_table)                            
                    print ("write out headers")                                     

                    for i = 1,table.maxn(field_table) do                            
                            print ("i: "..i)i                                       
                            table.insert(field_table,i,nil)                         
                    end                                                             



                    field_index = 1                                                 
            end     -- close loop for header

            print ("field index: "..field_index)                                    
            print ("max fields: "..max_fields)                                      
            if field_index >= max_fields and max_fields > 0 and header_true ~= 0 then 
                     print ("FT: "..field_table[4])                                  
                    print ("machine: "..machine)                                    
                    local match_string = field_table[4]                             
                    print (string.match(match_string, machine))                     
                    i, n = string.find(field_table[4], 'machine')                   
                    print (i,n)                                                     
                    if i ~= nil then                                                
                            print ("matchy")                                        
                    end
                    field_index = 1                                                 
            end




    end 
    end
```

end

end

=============================================================

Comment: Could you please add the result  of printing these both variables?

Comment: Can you show us the full code for this as I can only make guesses from seeing two variable names and nothing about how or what they were assigned to

Comment: thanks for your code. would you please just provide the text and the pattern as a string?

Comment: Not the exact text (which I don't want to/can't expose the data on.) but it is functionally the same is listed in the first part of this query

Comment: you cannot ask why a pattern does not match a text if you don't provide both. isn't that obvious? you just provide variable names. give an example that produces the same result as your real data

Answer (score 0):

So, there was nothing wrong with this.  My original match for the machine name was also capturing whitespace after the machine name.  I figured this out after printing the machine name surrounded by delimiters.  I had to add a trim function for this.

Here is the function I added:

`function trim(string)
        local trimmed = string:find"%S"
        return trimmed and string:match(".*%S", trimmed) or ""
   end`

This let me pass the machine name as a variable and cut the trailing whitespace.  It might have been better to cut the whitespace in the match, but I couldn't figure out a way to do that and leave it as a delimiter (which is important for tab separated values)